# Magento 2.4.4 PageBuilder SourceMaps not generated

Tags: css, magento2.4, 404, page-builder, magento2.4.4

I hope to get some help here.

I am using M2.4.4 with Pagebuilder on the backend. But on Product Edit Detail I get lots of 404 errors with missing .map files.

How can I disable PageBuilder SourceMaps or how to generate them?

[image: Magento PageBuilder SourceMaps Error]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Magento doesn't generate any source map files for JS. You can ignore those errors or disable warnings in your browser. This feature needs only for debug uglified code.

[How to fix the "DevTools failed to load SourceMap: Could not load content"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61205390/how-to-fix-the-devtools-failed-to-load-sourcemap-could-not-load-content-error)